# Hudson Build-Time Trend Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin which would allow me to create a "trend" graph for a hudson build which shows the build time for that project?

I'm tasked with speeding up the build and I'd like to show a nice trend as I speed it up.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is supported out of the box: http://SERVER/hudson/job/JOBNAME/buildTimeTrend

[image]

Comment: Just in case, it's the link "(trend") next to "Build History" on the left side in the box.

Comment: It's just a shame this is just for the builds in your history. It would be nice if it recorded a number of trends like 1 year, month etc.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Unfortunately the graph only shows 20 builds. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22008

Answer (score 18):

To follow up from the @Pascal's answer, if you would like to bring this graph and show it more prominently you can edit the job description and add an image directly there

```
<img src="http://test.vlc/job/flow_tester/buildTimeGraph/png" />
```

That way you can see the time trend every time you open the job.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to configure the look of the PNG image? instead of the build number on the x-axis, i'd like to see the build host...

Comment: Sorry @Dominik my answer was more about how to get the default image more prominently displayed.

Answer (score 7):

To follow up from the @Jamie Cooks's answer, you don't need to provide full url for this graph, you can just use the relative path like this in your job description -

```
<img src='buildTimeGraph/png' />
```

Benefit of this is that you don't need to change/customize the url for each job.

Moreover, to enable this on all your jobs you can use this groovy script

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.maven.*
import hudson.tasks.*

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) 
{
  println("job $item.name")
  item.setDescription("<img src='buildTimeGraph/png' />");
}
```