# Hudson plugin for trend of timings of all jobs in a view

Tags: plugins, time, hudson, trending

Is there a Hudson plugin which would allow me to create a "trend" graph for build times for all jobs/projects in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [supported for *one* job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772633/hudson-build-time-trend-plugin).

But for *all* jobs, the [Global Build Stats Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin) will be able to do that. However, it is not there yet.

Meaning you need to develop your own plugin, based on the [Plot Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin), to vizualise that kind of trend (build times)

[image]
<sub>(source: [hudson-ci.org](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/download/attachments/2752526/examplePlot.png?version=1&modificationDate=1184536762000))</sub>